# How can two classes with different underlying STL containers present the same iterator interface?

Tags: c++, stl, std

I'm implementing a functionality which will operate on sampled sensor values. Depending on how these values are obtained (read from file or sampled real-time) I would like to use different underlying STL containers for storage (vector and deque). Of course the analysis logic shall not need to know the underlying storage. A design without iterators could look something like

```
class AbstractDataSource
{
   virtual double getValue(const size_t index) const = 0;
};

class FileDataSource : public AbstractDataSource
{
   double getValue(const size_t index) const { return ValueFromVector};
}

class RealtimeDataSource : public AbstractDataSource
{
   double getValue(const size_t index) const { return ValueFromDeqeue};
}
```

And then pass pointers to AbstractDataSource to the analysis parts.

But how can the same be accomplished if AbstractDataSource shall have an STL-like iterator interface with begin() and end() ? Since iterators are returned from begin() and and() by value an iterator cannot have pure virtual functions. Is the solution to define a kind of proxy iterator to AbstractDataSource? This proxy iterator would have a pointer to an iterator created by the derived class.

Comment: So you need to use iterator in base class, and implement in derived class?

Comment: If you can implement a virtual `getValue(index)` on the base class, then you can define an iterator that simply holds an index and an `AbstractDataSource*` pointer, and calls `getValue` when dereferenced.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, this would work but iterating through the values would be very inefficient if the underlying data storage is anything for which random access is expensive, for example a linked list.

Comment: @yao99 No, other classes using the base class interface shall be able to access the data via an iterator.

Comment: You could either implement a [type-erased](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/basic.html) iterator type that can hold any iterator type or, if you are only ever return `vector` or `deque` iterators, you could implement a `vector_deque_iterator` holding a `std::variant<std::vector<T>::iterator, std::duque<T>::iterator>` and use `std::visit` to implement the iterator interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface for iterators like:

```
template <class T>
class ContainerIterator {
public:
    virtual ~ContainerIterator() = default;
    virtual T& operator*() = 0;
    virtual ContainerIterator<T>& operator++() = 0;
    virtual bool operator!=(const ContainerIterator<T>&) const = 0;
    virtual ContainerIterator<T>* copy() = 0;
};
```

And implement the interfase for all types of iterators by template like:

```
template <class T, class I>
class ContainerIteratorImpl: public ContainerIterator<T>{
public:
    I it;
    ContainerIteratorImpl(const I &_it):it(_it) {}
    T& operator*()
    {
        return *it;
    }
    ContainerIterator<T>& operator++()
    {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator!=(const ContainerIterator<T> &rhs) const
    {
        return it != dynamic_cast<const ContainerIteratorImpl<T,I>&>(rhs).it;
    }
    ContainerIteratorImpl<T,I>* copy()
    {
        return new ContainerIteratorImpl<T,I>(it);
    }
};
```

But if directly use `ContainerIterator` like:

```
ContainerIterator<double> it = data.begin();
```

compile will output an error like `error: cannot declare variable ‘it’ to be of abstract type` since the base class `ContainerIterator<double>` is an abstract class, i.e. it is not implemented, so we cannot have an instance of it.

That is result from a C++ variable store the value, not the reference. So in C++, we cannot store an instance of a derived class in a variable of the base class. e.g.

```
Base base = Derived(); // base is a variable
```

The program call the copy constructor of `Base`, and the base is not a instance of `Derived`.

But if we use pointer like

```
Derived derived();
Base *base = &derived; // base is a pointer
```

`base` is pointed to an instance of `Derived`.

So we need to create a wrapper for `ContainerIterator`, and let us can create an object to handle defferent iterators like:

```
template <class T>
class Iterator {
public:
    ContainerIterator<T> *pit;
    Iterator():pit(0) {}
    Iterator(const Iterator &x):pit(x.pit->copy()) {}
    template <class I>
    Iterator(const I &it):pit(new ContainerIteratorImpl<T,I>(it)){}
    ~Iterator()
    {
        delete pit;
    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        return **pit;
    }
    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++*pit;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator &rhs) const
    {
        return *pit != *rhs.pit;
    }
    Iterator& operator=(const Iterator &rhs)
    {
        delete pit;
        pit = rhs.pit->copy();
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Finally, `Interator` can contain different types of iterators. So you can declare `begin()` and `end()` in the base class, and implement in derived classes like:

```
class AbstractDataSource
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractDataSource() = default;
    virtual Iterator<double> begin() = 0;
    virtual Iterator<double> end() = 0;
};
class FileDataSource : public AbstractDataSource
{
public:
    std::vector<double> data;
    FileDataSource(const std::vector<double> &_data):data(_data) {}
    Iterator<double> begin()
    {
        return Iterator<double>(data.begin());
    }
    Iterator<double> end()
    {
        return Iterator<double>(data.end());
    }
};
class RealtimeDataSource : public AbstractDataSource
{
public:
    std::deque<double> data;
    RealtimeDataSource(const std::deque<double> &_data):data(_data) {}
    Iterator<double> begin()
    {
        return Iterator<double>(data.begin());
    }
    Iterator<double> end()
    {
        return Iterator<double>(data.end());
    }
};
```

Demo:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

template <class T>
class ContainerIterator {
public:
    virtual ~ContainerIterator() = default;
    virtual T& operator*() = 0;
    virtual ContainerIterator<T>& operator++() = 0;
    virtual bool operator!=(const ContainerIterator<T>&) const = 0;
    virtual ContainerIterator<T>* copy() = 0;
};

template <class T, class I>
class ContainerIteratorImpl: public ContainerIterator<T>{
public:
    I it;
    ContainerIteratorImpl(const I &_it):it(_it) {}
    T& operator*()
    {
        return *it;
    }
    ContainerIterator<T>& operator++()
    {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator!=(const ContainerIterator<T> &rhs) const
    {
        return it != dynamic_cast<const ContainerIteratorImpl<T,I>&>(rhs).it;
    }
    ContainerIteratorImpl<T,I>* copy()
    {
        return new ContainerIteratorImpl<T,I>(it);
    }
};

template <class T>
class Iterator {
public:
    ContainerIterator<T> *pit;
    Iterator():pit(0) {}
    Iterator(const Iterator &x):pit(x.pit->copy()) {}
    template <class I>
    Iterator(const I &it):pit(new ContainerIteratorImpl<T,I>(it)){}
    ~Iterator()
    {
        delete pit;
    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        return **pit;
    }
    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++*pit;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator &rhs) const
    {
        return *pit != *rhs.pit;
    }
    Iterator& operator=(const Iterator &rhs)
    {
        delete pit;
        pit = rhs.pit->copy();
        return *this;
    }
};

class AbstractDataSource
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractDataSource() = default;
    virtual Iterator<double> begin() = 0;
    virtual Iterator<double> end() = 0;
};

class FileDataSource : public AbstractDataSource
{
public:
    std::vector<double> data;
    FileDataSource(const std::vector<double> &_data):data(_data) {}
    Iterator<double> begin()
    {
        return Iterator<double>(data.begin());
    }
    Iterator<double> end()
    {
        return Iterator<double>(data.end());
    }
};

class RealtimeDataSource : public AbstractDataSource
{
public:
    std::deque<double> data;
    RealtimeDataSource(const std::deque<double> &_data):data(_data) {}
    Iterator<double> begin()
    {
        return Iterator<double>(data.begin());
    }
    Iterator<double> end()
    {
        return Iterator<double>(data.end());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AbstractDataSource *fds = new FileDataSource({1,2,3});
    AbstractDataSource *rds = new RealtimeDataSource({4,5,6});
    Iterator<double> it;
    for(it = fds->begin(); it != fds->end(); ++it)
    {
        printf("%f\n",*it);
    }
    for(it = rds->begin(); it != rds->end(); ++it)
    {
        printf("%f\n",*it);
    }
    delete fds;
    delete rds;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
6.000000
```

Comment: This was approximately what I would have tried but I hoped for something simpler.

Comment: I'm getting memory corruption if I try this on larger data samples. commenting out "delete pit;" from ~Iterator solves it but of course creates a memory leak.

Comment: the solution would be even better with a unique_ptr instead of the ContainerIterator<T> *.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [Boost.TypeErasure](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/operators.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
namespace te  = boost::type_erasure;

template <typename T>
using any_iterator = te::any<
    mpl::vector<te::copy_constructible<>, te::assignable<>, te::incrementable<>,
                te::dereferenceable<T>, te::equality_comparable<>>>;

int main(int, char**) {
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
  any_iterator<int> b = v.begin();
  any_iterator<int> e = v.end();
  std::copy(b, e, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Here, `any_iterator` should in principle model a [forward_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator). One could also specialize [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to make the `value_type` visible for algorithms. IT should be straightforward to generalize this to bidirectional or random-access iterators. Under the hood, it should be equivalent to the solution of yao99.

Comment: Thanks, I have some reading to do do understand this solution.